# From server cannot ping server itself by its hostname while can ping by its IP

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ping, hostname, resolv.conf

I host an ubuntu server at a data center and worked well for years till last night the server can not ping itself by host name. No config has been changed. Here are what it can/can not do now.

- From outside, I can ping the server both by its static IP, and by its hostname.
- From server, I can ping any website (google, yahoo, ...).
- From server, I can ping localhost, and can ping the IP of server itself.
- From server, I can **not** ping sever itself by its hostname.

Here is `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/* 

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp5s0

iface enp5s0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.134
netmask 255.255.255.128
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.255
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.129
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

and `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and the output of `route -n` is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.xxx.129 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
xxx.xxx.xxx.128 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 enp5s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

These configs worked for years. Wondering what happened? Thanks.

Comment: Just put your servers IP + the hostname(s) into your `/etc/hosts` file. 
`x.x.x.x somehostname.com hostname`

Comment: When you run the `ping` command, what IP address does it say it’s using?

Comment: @G-Man ping stalls.

Comment: @Michael D, that worked, thank you! Wondering how come I did not need it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check /etc/hosts. Probably there's a line with the name of the server and an incorrect IP